# Think outside the box

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, anglicismes

> One should aspire to think outside the box.

Google Translate donne

> Il faut aspirer à sortir des sentiers battus.

Selon linguee :

https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/ability+to+think+outside+the+box.html

plusieurs interprétations existent pour "think outside the box".

Parmi d'autres, on voit : "hors des sentiers battus".
Cette dernière-ci est-elle courante/idiomatique ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oui! Absolument. Ta traduction est correcte et courante.

On notera non sans amusement que les différentes traductions possibles dépendent, en France, du milieu...

- A *sortir des sentiers battus* est le plus fréquent en arts et en sciences.
- B *secouer les paradigmes* dans le langage de communication d'entreprise.
- C *penser autrement* dans le langage politique.
- D *lever le nez du guidon* dans le langage de... ceux qui... bossent pour de vrai... ;-)

L'expression en anglais étant apparue pour la première fois dans un contexte de conduite d'entreprise, dans ce contexte, ma préférence irait à B.

Comment: Recommander *secouer les paradigmes*, c'est plus que sortir des sentiers battus ! L'expression risque d'être incomprise par beaucoup. Google books n'en trouve qu'une seule occurrence et Google tout court en trouve moins de dix... D'autre part, *lever le nez du guidon*, ce n'est pas vraiment la même chose. On ne sort pas forcément des sentiers battus après avoir levé le nez du guidon, on cesse seulement d'être totalement focalisé sur la tâche en cours.

Comment: @jlliagre : Lean Sigma VA->VF!

Comment: D'autant que dans la communication d'entreprise, nombreux sont ceux qui reprendront l'expression anglaise.

Comment: @LaurentS. : C'est curieux certes mais... il se trouve que non.( cf https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32058/lean-manufacturing ) On ne traduit pas le titre mais... ce qui est à l'intérieur... si!

Comment: @aCOSwt > La France n'est pas la francophonie. Je ne sais pas ce qu'il en est en France, où il y a une tendance à tout traduire donc il est bien possible que ca ne soit pas le cas, mais de mon côté, en Belgique, j'ai souvent vu le "thinking out of the box". Mais c'est très clairement une question culturelle : parfois l'anglais est prédominant simplement car c'est dans cette langue que les échanges se font entre collègues non-bilingues francais/néerlandais...

Comment: @LaurentS. : Les plus ardents adeptes de la traduction à tout prix ne sont pas des Hégonaux... ;-)

Comment: ACOSwt, je ne comprends pas ce que ta réponse à mon commentaire a à voir avec celui-ci.

Comment: @jlliagre : Une source qui avait le mérite d'être sous mes yeux à cet instant-là. Mais il en est bien d'autres. La comm interne d'entreprise n'ayant pas vraiment vocation à se retrouver sur Google.

Comment: Google indexe suffisamment de documents de tout genre pour qu'une telle référence puisse être remise en cause. Elle peut néanmoins très bien être fondée mais encourager son utilisation n'est pas ce qu'il y a de mieux à proposer à quelqu'un qui apprend le français, sauf à mieux préciser le côté ridicule de l'expression.

Comment: @jlliagre : C'est ton... opinion! Et en écrivant : "*ma préférence*" je n'ai pas fait une reco, j'ai donné... la mienne.

Comment: OK, une opinion qui semble cependant bien singulière. Il reste que *sortir des sentiers battus* n'est pas l'équivalent de *lever le nez du guidon*.