# Lean manufacturing

Tags: traduction, anglais, anglicismes

Dans des polycopiés distribués j'ai rencontré le terme anglais lean manufacturing. Peut-on employer le terme tel il est déhors le monde académique ou est-ce mieux d'utiliser une interprétation française parmi celles rencontrés sur linguee ?

Comment: Si ta question est *peut-on employer **lean manufacturing** en dehors du monde académique*, il faudrait que tu précises à quel milieu tu t'adresses mais à priori, je dirais non car cette formule spécialisée est inconnue de la plupart des français. Tout le monde comprendra *manufacturing* grâce à la proximité avec le français, mais *lean* laissera perplexes beaucoup d'entre nous qui ne connaissent souvent même pas son sens original (incliné).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans l'industrie (car c'est l'application à l'origine), tous les supports de formation en V.F. / formateurs utilisent *lean*. Que ce soit seul ou composé : *lean manufacturing, lean management, lean sigma...*

Je dirai donc oui absolument. Garder tel pour être compris.

Je sais (et respecte) néanmoins l'initiative de la *Commission d'enrichissement de la langue française* qui a tenu à franciser ces termes :

- Lean administration - > Administration allégée
- Lean manufacturing - > Production au plus juste

Comme on pourra voir [ici](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme). Mais j'admets n'avoir jamais encore entendu ou lu cette terminologie française employée en entreprise.

Comment: Merci vivement. Je pense que la situation est la même avec le couple brainstorming et rémue-méninge, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: @dimitris : C'est différent en ce que *lean-xyzt* se réfèrent à des méthodes, règles, pincipes, grades... tout est relativement codifié. Il est assez inusuel de chercher à traduire les noms référents. *Brainstorming* est une activité beaucoup moins codifiée avec peut-être des codes mais locaux et informels, tout le monde l'entend un peu comme il veut et traduira volontiers et... comme il veut.